# ksoap2-android how to view soap message being sent?

Tags: android, ksoap2

I have enabled debug mode by setting `httpTransport.debug = true`. However, `httpTransport.requestDump` does not show anything. May I have a hint as to why it is not working please? Is there any way I can view the soap message created in the envelope?

Thank you very much for your help.

```
final String NAMESPACE = getString(R.string.namespace);
final String METHOD_NAME = getString(R.string.method_name);
final String SOAP_ACTION = getString(R.string.soap_action);
final String SERVICE_URL = getString(R.string.service_url);
final String API_KEY = getString(R.string.api_key);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("<APIKey>");
sb.append(API_KEY);
sb.append("</APIKey><ISBN>");
sb.append(ean);
sb.append("</ISBN><Modifiers></Modifiers>");
Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
// GetAvailabilityInfoRequest availability = new GetAvailabilityInfoRequest(API_KEY, ean);
request.addProperty("GetAvailabilityInfoRequest", sb.toString());

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = false;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SERVICE_URL);
httpTransport.debug = true;
try {
    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    Log.d(TAG, httpTransport.requestDump);
    Log.d(TAG, httpTransport.responseDump);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error ", e);
}
```

This is my request,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
    xmlns:soap="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">; 
    <soap:Body>
        <GetAvailabilityInfoRequest xmlns="nlb.gov.sg/ws/CatalogueService">; 
            <APIKey>****APIKEY***</APIKey>
            <ISBN>9781579124854</ISBN>
            <Modifiers></Modifiers>
        </GetAvailabilityInfoRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Best Regards,
JN

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: updated question with code snippet...

Comment: Are there any errors in Logcat?

Comment: Nope, there is no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to create a request as follows,

```
<Body>
    <GetAvailabilityInfoRequest>
        <APIKey>key</APIKey>
        <ISBN>ean</ISBN>
        <Modifiers></Modifiers>
    </GetAvailabilityInfoRequest>
</Body>
```

Also I assume your `METHOD_NAME` is `GetAvailabilityInfoRequest`.

Try the following code to create the request,

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("APIKey", key);
request.addProperty("ISBN", ean);
request.addProperty("Modifiers", "");

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = false;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
```

Comment: Hi Neeraj, unfortunately I got an error message of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." from the service provider. Let me communicate with the administrator of the service to see what's wrong. Thanx.

Comment: BTW, the soap message that I wanna create is as follows, which I don't know how to set the namespaces for the tags: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<GetAvailabilityInfoRequest xmlns="http://www.nlb.gov.sg/ws/CatalogueService">
<APIKey>****APIKEY***</APIKey>
<ISBN>9781579124854</ISBN>
<Modifiers>
</Modifiers>
</GetAvailabilityInfoRequest>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: Hi Neeraj, thanx for your help. Your answer is actually correct and it's my fault for entering the wrong method name. A quick (potentially stupid) question though: is there a difference when adding a string property vs a integer property?

Comment: Yes there is. Incompatible datatypes can cause a server error. Good luck :)